# Change another content with navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-fragmentactivity, navigation-drawer

I am created default navigation drawer application with android studio.

[image]

Then i wan't to create different layout with different component.How can i change that content relevant to menu click.

I want to change this two content when click navigation menu links.
[image]

The dummy contents(!impotent: The content body is efferent,cannot use reusable fragments)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question right you can have a FrameLayout as a container. On List item click add or replace appropriate fragment to the container.

If you need to start a new activity you can do that also.

You can follow the example @

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create different layout with different component.How can i
>   change that content relevant to menu click.

=> I exactly got your point that you want to change the content aka layout (activity) whenever user select any items from a navigation drawer.

If this is the case then you have to replace the current fragment with new fragment that you would want to display.

For example:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                   .commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

For detailed example: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html